# VISA. Как принять на сайте?

Tags: php, платежи

Кто-нибудь знает простое API (PHP), чтобы принимать платежи карт VISA?

Пробовал [это API](https://developer.visa.com/), но ничего не получилось. Довольно сложное API у них.

Comment: А почему именно VISA?
и принять куда Вы хотите?
это же счёт надо открыть сначала, значит в банк обращаться за счётом, а уж потом эквайринг, а банк принимает многие карты и VISA это одна из платёжных систем, и принимать платежи кстати, можно и без API и плагины написаны готовые для многих CMS и фреймы с кнопками силами самого банка

Comment: Как же без API принимать? Расскажите, пожалуйста)

Comment: смотря что за банк)) у многих всё написано уже, на память 2 сразу вспоминается, выбирайте правильный и открывайте счёт для эквайринга там будет 2 счёта для ЮЛ, это норм... но попробуйте сначала с вашим банком разобраться, если выбран уже, у многих есть, эта возможность, а вопросы к ним в ТП, или пишите в ЛС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заключить договор с каким-то конкретным банком на эквайринг и пользоваться его API для приёма карт.

Детали в каждом банке разные и обычно под NDA. Но в целом API весьма похожие выходят и сроки подключения всегда небыстрые, СБ проверяет.

Админку дают... чтобы можно было транзакции отменять, я помнится много транзакций делал с личной карты, потом отменял.

А это похоже вы вообще нашли  API свой визы для банков, что-то я никогда не видел такого, чтобы Visa сама напрямую отдельные юрлица подключала, это ж огромная система, виза с банками работает, а они уже -- с вами, отдельными юрлицами.

Сложность API... ну как вам сказать, они все примерно одинаковые, тут уж нужно понимать свой уровень квалификации как программиста.

Приём денег -- это жесткий бизнес, завязанный на безопасность, если вы не тянете -- то может и не стоит?

Comment: Может, мне тогда вообще ничем не заниматься?)

Comment: @VIPER Не хочу отвечать на провокационные вопросы. Сами оцените свои силы и решите, чем вам заниматься. Я просто вам так скажу: руководство фирмы вряд ли будет перебирать даже десяток банков, чтобы подождать, пока программиста устроит их API. Проще поменять программиста на того, который тянет.

Comment: Я работал с несколькими API для платежек, да, они почти все одинаковые. Но этот завел меня в тупик. Хорошо, чтобы было корректно я поправлю, что API было сложно конкретно для меня. Признаю свой низкий уровень но сдаваться не буду)

Comment: В целом спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Буду изучать, чтобы такие, как Вы говорили, что я шарю :)

Comment: Не сдавайтесь, это правильное и похвальное качество, повышайте свой уровень и квалификацию. Просто ещё раз повторю: сколько видел платёжных систем и сколько банков интегрировал -- всё примерно одно и то же. Но чтобы напрямую с API визы работать -- вижу в первый раз. Вы работаете в банке? Вряд ли. Значит это не ваше API.

Comment: Концепцию уяснил. Благодарен Вам!)